# Is it necessary to have an additional "None" class for classification tasks for unknown inputs?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

The idea is to have an additional class that would be "triggered" whenever there's an unknown/ambiguous input. Ideally, a ML model should do this by itself: it should for example return softmax output values that are close together when the input is ambiguous.

But when it's not the case, would having this additional class that holds "noisy" data be beneficial? And what are some best practices or known techniques, if any, for building such a class.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a softmax activation then yes a None class would be necessary if you're dealing with data that you're sure has inputs that are unknown or ambiguous.
However, you'll need to figure out a way to add the same label to your training data so your model can learn.

Another way to do this would be to use sigmoid activation function and when the probability of all classes is low, then you know that the example probably belongs to the ambiguous class.
The reason this can't be done with softmax is that softmax probabilities always add up to 1. This means that the model will try to fit every example into one class or another.